# c++ stl - manually using standard gdb pretty printers

Tags: python, c++, stl, gdb

How can i use StdVectorPrinter of https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-6_3_0-release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py to create my own output style?
I.e. use the existing tools for element access, but drive the output on my own.

E.g. for

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::vector<std::string> data = { "hello", "world", "all", "is", "fine" };

    for ( auto && i : data) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output shall not be

```
(gdb) p data
$2 = std::vector of length 5, capacity 5 = {"hello", "world", "all", "is", "fine"}
```

But

```
(gdb) p data
$2 = "hello|world|all|is|fine"
```

Where is the skeleton code for the generic printer, that uses the StdVectorPrinter (e.g.)?

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the skeleton code for the generic printer, that uses the StdVectorPrinter

That may depend on your OS. On Ubuntu:

```
$ dpkg -L libstdc++6:amd64 | grep '\.py'
/usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/__init__.py
/usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/__init__.py
/usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py
/usr/share/gcc-8/python/libstdcxx/v6/xmethods.py
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
```

The `printers.py` contains this line:

```
    libstdcxx_printer.add_container('std::', 'vector', StdVectorPrinter)
```

which associates `StdVectorPrinter` with `std::vector`. You can override the `StdVectorPrinter` itself, or you can associate `std::vector` with a different pretty-printer.

Answer (score 2):

This does the job - but it doesn't use the StdVectorPrinter iterators:

```
(gdb) py
>data = gdb.parse_and_eval("data")
>count = data['_M_impl']['_M_finish'] - data['_M_impl']['_M_start']
>result = ''
>data = data['_M_impl']['_M_start']
>for x in range(int(count)):
> result = result + str((data + x).dereference())[1:-1] + '|'
>print (result)
>end
hello|world|all|is|fine|
(gdb)
```

Using the iterators would work for other containers as well.